# net 4.7 service install upgrade

Tags: c#

I inherited a .net service project which does not support TLS 1.2, project was upgraded to .net 4.7. Previous .exe file was replaced with the new 4.7exe and the service was restarted.  Service cannot be started due to error "1064:An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request"

Do I have to use installutil.exe MyNewService.exe to install a service?

The installutil.exe is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319, would this support .net 4.7  or do I need to download and install .NET Framework 4.7 offline installer for Windows?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions, I am not familiar with .net services!

Comment: Thanks for responding. What would be the correct NET\Framework\v4... version for 4.7?   I upgraded on my PC but still show the Framework as v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you include all output files from the build, including the app.config file. There might be assembly redirects there which are required by 4.7.

Is the correct .NET Framework version installed on the server you're running the service on?

If that doesn't help, try running the application from command prompt, if your application supports it (I recommend it should). If that works, the service user running the service might be missing some permissions.

Add logging. As minimum, add try-catch statements in your service entry points and log any exceptions to a file. You can also add a handler to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which will -usually- be called before the application crashes.